# How can I delete a user from entire multisite nework

Tags: multisite, users

I'm making a front-end user delete button but it only removes the user from the current installation and I need to remove them from the entire multisite network so they are able to sign up again with the same email if they decide. Is there a way to do this?

```
$userid = get_current_user_id();
wp_delete_user( $userid );
```

Comment: Can we see the current implementation? Edit your question and insert the code that does the deletion

Comment: Yes I just added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to use `wpmu_delete_user`:

```
$userid = get_current_user_id();
wpmu_delete_user( $userid );
```

> Deletes a user from the network and removes it from all sites.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_delete_user/

Comment: Totally agree the function is the way to go, but the demo code seems a little dangerous as it would delete the current user. Rarely what you'd want to do, and could cause some serious issues for anyone blindly copying and pasting :) (I've been there). Would recommend changing to just a random integer with a note to change it in comments